# How to slow down mouse before modifyend with openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, markers, mouse-cursor

I have a map with a draggable marker (ol.style.icon in fact).
There is a strange issue:
If I try to move marker, it is like trying to reel in a marlin but after a zoomin/out, marker naturally slows down.
I tried to play with PixelTolerance but any difference.
Why and how to immediately slow down this marker, please?

```
var mark_style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [.5, 48],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: mark_path
 })
});

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature(position);
iconFeature.set('style', mark_style);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style: function(feature) {
        return feature.get('style');
    },
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [iconFeature]})
})
var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: new ol.Collection([iconFeature]),
  style: null,
  pixelTolerance: 10//?
});

dragInteraction.on('modifyend',function(f){
    var coordf = f.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    ol.View-view.setCenter(coordf);
    },iconFeature);

  map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
```

Comment: Well, it seems it is a 'modifyend' problem. Mouse is fast before first dragInteraction end. How to do? with a modifystart, no more speed up but then, how to access all mouse positions after first clic ?

Comment: no better with pointerdrag... any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, seems ok with `dragInteraction.on(['modifyend', 'modifystart']`

Comment: Seriously? Did you read all my first post? With this, you should have understood my answer. I'm a beginner and I don't know why my code is now ok. I succeeded after lot of tries.